# Polymer dom-repeat filter Uncaught TypeError

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

While executing my code, which makes use of dom-repeat, filter and observe, I get the following **error**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined  VM8037 polymer-mini.html:2057
   _filterFn @ VM8038 polymer.html:4147
    (anonymous function) @ VM8038 polymer.html:4282
    Polymer._applyFullRefresh @ VM8038 polymer.html:4281
    Polymer._render @ VM8038 polymer.html:4231
    Debouncer.complete @ VM8037 polymer-mini.html:2095
    boundComplete @ VM8037 polymer-mini.html:2074
    Polymer.Async._atEndOfMicrotask @ VM8037 polymer-mini.html:2051
    window.MutationObserver.observe.characterData @ VM8037 polymer-mini.html:2066
```

If I remove the attributes "filter" and "observe" from `<template>`, "dom-repeat" works fine, otherwise "dom-repeat" fails and the menu items are not rendered.

**index.html code:**

```
...
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
   ...
    <template id="tmenu" is="dom-repeat" items="{{content.sections}}"
          filter="dataFilters.showUnpublished" observe="item.published">
        <paper-button raised class="top-nav">
            <a data-route="{{item.route}}" href="{{baseUrl}}{{item.route}}">
                <span>{{item.menu}}</span>
           </a>
       </paper-button>
   </template>
</template>
...
```

**app.js code:**

```
...
app.dataFilters = {
    // called by the templates that "renders" the top and the drawer menus.
    showUnpublished: function(item) {
        console.log(item);
        if (app.sysVars.granted && app.sysVars.signedIn) {
            console.log(true);
            return true;
        }
        console.log(false);
        return item.published; //item.published is a boolean
    }
};
app.content = { project: {}, sections: [] };
window.addEventListener('gapiLoaded', function() {
    ...
    // prior code retrieves the content from the server 
    // and injects it using the following 2 lines:
    app.set('content.sections', resp.sections);
    app.set('content.project', resp.project);
    ...
)};
...
```

Could the error be an indication of a Polymer bug?

Am I doing something wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `observe="published"` instead of `observe="item.published"`?

Comment: I found the source of the issue. As soon as possible, I will post what I have found. :)

Comment: @sam_dw Did you find a solution?